# Stop one Video if try to play another react native

Tags: video, react-native

I have a list in which I have listed various video and audio. I am using the react-native-video-player library. If I play a video it starts playing, if I click on another video in the list it also starts playing, both videos are getting played at the same time, I also have some audios in the list. I want to check interruptions, if some media is playing and I click on another media file, then the previous file should stop playing.

Comment: There is a feature request on that repository, you can only wait for 0the developer to do it or find another library https://github.com/cornedor/react-native-video-player/issues/17

Comment: But how to check general media intruptions, like in My list I also have audio files. If I play those files then the other file which is playing should shtoo. I want to stop any media file playing, if I click on another file whether audio or video,